# How to extend a video by freezing the last frame without reencoding the whole stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding, video-editing

I'd like to achieve two things without re-encoding the whole video stream:

1. Extend a video by freezing the last frame for a given duration.
2. Extend a video by freezing a frame at a given timestamp for a given duration.

Currently I'm using `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=5 out.mp4` but it requires encoding the whole video stream and only allows freezing the last frame of the stream. To get my desired result I need to split the video into segments, extract the last second of a segment to a separate file (so I re-encode just that part), run the above command on it and then merge all the segments back with concat demuxer.

Is there any better and simpler way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To 'extend' the the last frame, extend the audio stream by padding it.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v copy -af apad -t 5 out.mp4
```

If there's no existing audio stream, add one

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v copy -af apad -t 5 out.mp4
```

---

For pausing a frame in the middle with minimal re-encoding , segmenting + concat is indeed the way to go

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gyan! And if I wanted to actually modify the video track instead of adding a dummy audio track, is the `-vf tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=5 ` the correct approach?

Comment: Yes, tpad is the way to go.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! This works because when the video and audio are different lengths, it will extend the shorter stream to match the longer one by default (unless you use the `-shortest` option).

Comment: note that the `-t 5` argument is the length in seconds of the final output, not the length that you want to extend the input by.

Comment: how do i convert the extended mp4 to a gif ? if i convert the extended mp4 to a gif ffmpeg trims the video to the non extended version. Why ?